# Density estimation: the significance of smaller number of samples?

Tags: graphical-model, density-estimation

I'm reading *Probabilistic Graphical Model: Principle and Techniques* by Koller and Friedman. In section 18.5 Bayesian Model Averaging(p825), the author said

> If we are interested only in density estimation, this might not be a serious problem.

[image]

Could anyone explain why smaller number of samples is not a serious problem for density estimation?